# Number of field homomorphisms between a finite and infinite field and vice versa?

Tags: abstract-algebra

What can we say about the number of field homomorphisms $h:K \to K'$ whit $K$ and $K'$ finite and infinite (4 cases)?

Comment: If $|K|>|K'|$ or the fields have different characteristic, then there are clearly none ...

Comment: How many embeddinngs $\Bbb{Q \to F_p}$ and $\Bbb{F_p \to Q}$ ? Where do you see 2 more cases ?

Comment: @reuns I think he means also the two cases with boths fields finite or non-finite.